# How to add a word to a row in crystal Report in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server, crystal-reports

I am doing an application in which I have to print some data using crystal report,
 for the data I am using MySql.
 In my database, I have a field which shows numbers of months so it is something like this:

> Table
>  User-------     Prevision
>  Test-------     3 MONTHS

So, in my database my column prevision shows the number of months and what I need is to add MONTHS to the field in crystal report...
PS: I don't want to add "MONTHS" in the database but only show it in the crystal report.
I can do it in datagrid easily but in crystal report I didn't make it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add concatenation in your SQL query, so it will return '3 months' instead of just '3'

something like this

select prevision + ' months ' as Test from YOUR_TABLE_NAME

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the code and trace the value being fetched in the dataset you are using to populate the crystal report..

Comment: what query you have used?

Comment: cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT NumId,Code, Creation,Prevision + ' MONTHS' as Prevision FROM tb_en20po2  this one but in the crystal report I am getting this values 3,00 4,00 I think it is adding not concatenating

Comment: Prevision + ' MONTHS' as P

Comment: In crystal report the detail field type must be string in which the Prevision is showing up.

Comment: I did this and it worked concat(Prevision, ' ', 'MONTHS') as Prevision Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

if you're saying you need to add the text "MONTHS" to your month value "3" and it is not currently there, you can create a Formula field in Crystal.  The formula would be something like:

```
{Tablename.Prevision} + " MONTH"
```

This will add the text MONTH to your prevision value for each row if you use the field within your Crystal report.

Comment: I am using a MySql query to add dynamically the data to the crystal report